# Binding multiple text boxes with multiple submitt buttons in same form

Tags: forms

I have a form where I have a search functionality with a text box(TextBox1) and a submitt button(Button1). Apart from search, there is another set of textbox(TextBox2) and submitt button(Button2). When I write something in search box(TextBox1), and hit enter, the validation message of the second textbox(TextBox2) is shown. 
    I am not sure how to bind the respective textboxes with submitt buttons. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much control you have, the easiest way would be to have separate forms for each texbox/button combo.

```
 <form action="dosomething.php">
   <input type="text" name="foo" />
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
<form action="dosomethingelse.php">
  <input type="text" name="bar" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

If you can't or don't want to do that, you'll need to look at handling the `onkeydown` event on the text boxes to prevent an automatic submission. Something like `<input type="Text" name="foo" onkeydown="doSubmit(this); return false;" />`. Note the `return false;`, which prevents the default action from taking place.

Comment: cant we pass different parameters while the submit is called and the respective action is processed. Based on that probably I can handle the submit event as per the need..